# In TypeScript, How can I use a external function in a class constructor function and get value from callback and assign to a property

Tags: typescript

How can I assign "aaa" to a??I can't write getStr() in this class because it form a library

```
class a {
    aaa: String
    constructor(aaa) {
        getStr(function(str) {
            // this.aaa = str
        })
    }
}

function getStr(callback) {
    callback("aaa")
}
```

Comment: You can, but the property will be set only after the callback is called, not immediately when the object is created.

Comment: And you might have to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to get the correct `this` inside your callback.

Comment: @Saravana Thankyou very much, I just change to use the arrow functions and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have callback I assume we are talking about async execution. In this case the answer is

#### You cannot

By definition constructor must return instance of the constructed class. This is important. Not a `Promise<MyClass>`, not a `Promise<void>`. Therefore what you are trying to archive is not possible.

Please do not follow the illusion that you can call async function in constructor and it will do the work. It will be finished sometime after constructor code is finished executing, or maybe not - depending on other code that gets executed alongside. This uncertainty - makes this approach extremely dangerous and unpredictable.

What you can do - usually if you need to perform some initialization of the instance that requires async calls - you create a separate `init(): promise<void>` function that can be correctly called and awaited.